# Use wiped iPhone 5s as an iPod

Tags: iphone, itunes, ipod-touch

I want to use my old iPhone 5s as an iPod.

It showed Wi-Fi service before the cellular service broke and but tech support was unable to repair it so we wiped it clean and tried to restore functions by connecting to iTunes but it will not connect to set up.

How can I get it to work so I can use with wifi as an iPod?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) The question as it is written is a bit hard to understand. Kindly consider [editing](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/333376/edit) it to make it clear to get quick and helpful answers.

Comment: Christine, it isn't clear what state the iPhone is currently in, from the sounds of it you have restored the iPhone but you are unable to activate it using iTunes or Wi-Fi. Could you tell us more about what you've tried and what problems and error messages you've encountered.

Comment: There are dozens of questions answering this for iPhone to iPhone X and all have the same answer of yes. You don’t need cellular service or radio for the iPhone to work. Only WiFi when you need data and occasionally to set up.

Comment: If you have a specific error in iTunes - please edit that in the post and flag for a review of the close.